# Swift: cannot invoke 'addObject' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?!)'

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, populate

I have created an array, empty atm: `var textArray: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()`

I'm trying to populate this Array with datas like this tutorial: https://youtu.be/0qE8olxB3Kk but my datas are not simple Strings like he does, they are gotten from a JSON (an array of dictionaries) and are of type `AnyObject?!` I can update this topic with how I did if needed, but I won't overload this post with excessive code if they're useless.

When I populate my array like this: `self.textArray.addObject(summary)`

I have the error message `cannot invoke 'addObject' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?!)'`

where `summary` is one of my JSON Dictionary, of type `AnyObject?!`.

I know Arrays are supposed to be populated by data of type `AnyObject`..
Is there a way to convert an `AnyObject?!` to an `AnyObject`? I haven't seen any type like `...?!`so maybe the problem is there, I don't know...

Thank you for your help, I can update this topic with how I extract the dictionaries from the JSON I get by an HTTP Post Request or with any other informations.

Regards,

fselva

Comment: What do you mean by "AnyObject?!" ? indicate an optional, ! is a unwrap operator What you wrote sounds strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap the optional twice.

```
var textArray: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

var a:AnyObject?! = "hello"
```

You could do this with force unwraps:

```
textArray.addObject(a!!)
```

But that is unsafe and will crash if either optional is `nil`.  The way to do it safely is to use optional binding:

```
if let temp1 = a, temp2 = temp1 {
    textArray.addObject(temp2)
}
```

Comment: This safe solution seems to be the good one, thank you @vacawama, didn't know we can unwrap twice like this

Answer (score 2):

You have to *double unwrap* the `AnyObject?!` variable:

```
let obj = "Alice" as AnyObject?!
var arr = [AnyObject]()
arr.append(obj!!)
```

Comment: We are close to be okay, I have `Cannot invoke 'addObject' with an argument list of type(())`

The arr is of type [(AnyObject)] maybe it's the reason why?

Comment: If the type is `(AnyObject)`, that means a *tuple* containing an AnyObject. Your `summary` variable is probably a tuple.

Comment: I'll remind me what a tuple is, probably.

Comment: My solution works but you're right, @vacawama's one is better because it's more safe. As for the tuple, I'm just guessing, given your comment. Not sure 100% without seeing how your objects are actually declared.